# How to write a method in Objective-C of no class?

Tags: objective-c

Hello I have some experience with C++ and java and I'm a newbie to Objc and this question may be very silly. I am learning Objective-C by a book. So far all it teaches is writing methods of a class. I was wondering how to write a method belongs to no class in main.m.
 Like a simple `int max(a, b)` of Objective-C version and could be called by code in main function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what you need to know:

- All standard C is valid in a `.m` file.  All standard C++ is valid in a `.mm` file.  (A `.mm` file contains “Objective-C++” code.)
- A `.m` file is not required to contain a class implementation.  It can just contain function definitions if that's what you want.

So, you can just stick your function in `main.m` if that's what you want:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "AppDelegate.h"

int myMax(int a, int b)
{
    if (a > b) {
        return a;
    } else {
        return b;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

But you probably want to put it in a separate `.m` file, with a `.h` file.  The easiest way to create these files is choose File > New > File and then select the “Objective-C class”  template.  (In Xcode 6, the template is called either “Cocoa Touch Class” or “Cocoa Class” depending on your target platform.)  For the class name, just tell it the base filename you want your `.m` and `.h` to have.  (Example: enter `myMax` as the class.)  Make it a subclass of `NSObject`.

Then, edit the `.h` file, delete `@interface myMax` and all following lines, and declare your function:

```
//
//  myMax.h
//  polygon
//
//  Created by Rob Mayoff on 7/29/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Rob Mayoff. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

extern int myMax(int a, int b);
```

And in the `.m` file, delete `@implementation myMax` and all following lines, and define your function:

```
//
//  myMax.m
//  polygon
//
//  Created by Rob Mayoff on 7/29/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Rob Mayoff. All rights reserved.
//

#import "myMax.h"

int myMax(int a, int b)
{
    if (a > b) {
        return a;
    } else {
        return b;
    }
}
```

To use the function from `main.m`, you first need to `#import` the header file.  Then you just call the function with the usual C/C++ syntax:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "myMax.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSLog(@"myMax = %d", myMax(50, 60));
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

Note that since your function is defined in a `.m` file, it can use Objective-C syntax inside the function body.  Example:

```
//
//  myMax.m
//  polygon
//
//  Created by Rob Mayoff on 7/29/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Rob Mayoff. All rights reserved.
//

#import "myMax.h"

NSNumber *myMaxOfNumbers(NSNumber *a, NSNumber *b)
{
    if ([a doubleValue] > [b doubleValue]) {
        return a;
    } else {
        return b;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can not write Objective C method outside the class. But you can use C functions for it.

So you can just write the following:

```
int max(int a, int b)
{
    return a > b ? a : b;
}
```

And in `main` you can use this function in the following way:

```
int max = max(5, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write it. C code will work in Objective-C. If you want to write C++ code, you can write that too but in Objective-C++ (file with .mm extension).

Comment: So if I want to open a new file to write a method(of no class) in it which file type should I choose?

Comment: It depends on what you want, if you don't want to use Foundation or Cocoa data types, functions or classes, you can use '.c' file, otherwise you want '.m' or even '.mm' if you need C++ as well.

Answer (score -1):

Put this outside of the main function.

```
-(float)add:(float)num1 and:(float)num2
{
    return num1 + num2;
}
```

then call it within the main function like this:

```
[self add:3.5 and:4.3];
```

Comment: Methods that do not rely on the state of an instance should be class methods rather than instance methods (or free functions, depending on the context).